# Ubuntu からftp接続すると421 Service not available

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

windows Azure のVirtual Machinesで
Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTSを立ち上げ、
そのUbuntu 内から特定のftpに接続すると
421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection

ポートが21のftpだと接続はできます。
ポートが16910のftpだと、421となる

hosts.allow
hosts.deny
は、空の状態です。

何か設定などが必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: FTPサーバ側の `hosts.allow` に、ローカルのIPアドレスを追記してみていただけますか？

Comment: hosts.allowに127.0.0.1  それ以外にプライベート IP アドレス、パブリック IP アドレスを追加してみましが、変わらず　421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection　となり解決できませんでした。

Comment: FTPサーバ内部で自身のFTPサーバに16910番ポートからアクセスすることはできますか？もし出来るならばファイアウォールなどの設定の問題、出来なければFTPサーバの設定の問題に見えます。

Comment: > ftp ftp.xxxxxx.xx.xx 16910
> Connected to ftp.xxxxxx.xx.xx.
> 421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection

Connected後、すぐにcloseされてしまう感じです。

Comment: FTPサーバーのほうの製品名、設定、ログを（適宜マスクして）載せてもらうと回答も集まりやすいと思います。421 エラーは接続ユーザー数の制限に達したときなどに出るようです。あとFTPクライアントのデバッグオプションあるならその出力も確認し、 passive / active モードも両方ためしてみるのがいいんじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: サーバー側を管理している会社に対して要望を出し、解決しました。